WPF Datagrid Itemsource Parameter not calling the setter when child object is changed
i am working on a WPF application using caliburn micro.
I have a datagrid which has a list of a custom model as the itemsource.
The Model looks like this:
    public class ProductModel : Screen
    {
        private MyModel _value1 = new MyModel();
        private MyModel _value2 = new MyModel();
        private double _value3;

        public double ValueTotal 
        { 
            get
            {

                var sumMaxValues = _value1.MaxValue + _value2.MaxValue;
                var sumMinValues = _value1.MinValue + _value2.MinValue;

                return (sumMaxValues + sumMinValues) / 2;
            } 
        }
        public MyModel Value1
        {
            get { return _value1; }
            set
            {
                _value1 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ValueTotal);
            }
        }
        public MyModel Value2
        {
            get { return _c_value2; }
            set
            {
                __value2 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ValueTotal);
            }
        }
        public double Value3
        {
            get { return _value3; }
            set 
            { 
                _value3 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ValueTotal);         
            }
        }
    }

MyModel looks like this:
    public class MyModel
    {
        public double MinValue { get; set; }
        public double MaxValue { get; set; }
    }

My problem is that when I change value1 or value2 in the datagrid, ValueTotal does not update. However, when I change value3, it updates perfectly.
If it helps my xaml looks like this:
       <!--Main DataGrid -->
       <DataGrid x:Name="Products"
               AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
               CanUserAddRows="{Binding CanAddRows, FallbackValue=False}"
               IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, FallbackValue=True}"
               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

           <!--One column for every relevant row of RawMaterialModel-->
           <DataGrid.Columns>

               <!--value1-->
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="value1" Width="45">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding value1.MaxValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"
                                          Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlockStyle}"/>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding value1.MinValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"
                                          Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlockStyle}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBox Text="{Binding value1.MaxValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}" />
                               <TextBox Text="{Binding value1.MinValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>

               <!--value2-->
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="value2" Width="45">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding value2.MaxValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"
                                          Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlockStyle}"/>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding value2.MinValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"
                                          Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlockStyle}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBox Text="{Binding value2.MaxValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}" />
                               <TextBox Text="{Binding value2.MinValue, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>

               <!--Sum-->
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sum" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueTotal, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>

               <!--value3-->
               <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="value3" Width="70">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding value3, StringFormat='+ {0:0.00}'}"
                                          Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextBlockStyle}"/>
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <StackPanel>
                               <TextBox Text="{Binding value3, StringFormat='{}{0:0.00}'}" />
                           </StackPanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>


           </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>

I tried adding multiple NotifyOfPropertyChange in MyModel and in ProductModel with no success.
I also added logging to the setters of value 1, 2 and 3. When I changed min or max in the datagrid it never logged anything, so i guess the problem is that the setter isnt even called from the datagrid. But I dont know how to change that.

The problem you're experiencing is because the references for Value1 and Value2 are not changing (and nor should they).  The same is not true for value3 which is directly bound to the grid, so the property itself changes when you change the grid.
Remember changing a property on an object is NOT the same as changing the property reference itself.
A helpful way to illustrate this would be if you were to enhance the MyModel properties like so:
public class MyModel
{
  private double _minValue;
  public double MinValue 
  { 
    get => _minValue; 
    set 
    {
      _minValue = value;
      Console.Log("Updated min value");
    }
  }
...
}

You would see your logs.
There are a few ways to solve what you're trying to do.
Probably, the simplest way (both to understand and implement) is to flatten the properties in your ViewModel have four double properties.  Which pass-thru to your MyModel objects.
Something like this (x4):
private MyModel _value1;
public double Value1MinValue
{
  get => _value1.MinValue;
  set
  {
    _value1.MinValue = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ValueTotal);
  }
}

and then bind directly to Value1MinValue, Value1MaxValue, etc.

Your explanation is somewhat misleading. The fact that editing Value3 triggers a change notification has nothing to with the type of the property, i.e. "primitive type like double". It would work the same if Value3 would be a reference type. The important difference is just what you say initially, i.e. that Value1 and Value2 do not change when there is a property change in the referenced object. Besides that, there are no "pointers" involved here, just object references.

Good point, I've corrected the explanation to be more clear.

Thank you for your detailed answer. Your solution works great for a simple example like mine, but what would I do if I get 50 "MyModels" from a database. I cant implement endless properties. How would you solve this?

Would you have 50 <DataGridTemplateColumn> elements defined in your XAML?  How would you choose to build out all 50 columns for your UI?
